# Confusion about random variables and convergence in probabilty and distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm studying statistical analysis and there's something fundamental I'm missing about random variables and how they are used in defining convergence in probability or distribution:

In my syllabus (which is in dutch, so the terms i use might be slightly off), when talking about samples, it says that

> If we want to study the properties of a random variable $X$ in a 
>   target population, we take a random aselect sample of $n$ subjects from a
>   collection of $n$ random variables $X_1, ... X_n$ that are all
>   mutually (pairwise?) independent and which all have the same
>   distribution, namely that of $X$ in the target population.

A bit further, discussing convergence, it says

> An infinite row of random variables $X_1, X_2, ...$ on a probability
>   space converges in probability to $X$ if the folowing is true for each
>   $\epsilon > 0$: $\lim_{n\to\infty}{P(|X_n - X|)}  \geq 0$

What I don't understand is what $X_i$ actually means in these two contexts. I read it as follows: In the first part, it is presented as *one* choice from the population: $X_i$ is the length of the $i$th of $n$ people, for example. In the second part, it seems as if now $X_i$ represents the distribution of *all* $X_k$ ($k \leq n$), which of course tends towards the actual distribution $X$.

Do these $X$ mean different things? Am I completely missing something? Can anyone help me make sense of this?

Answer (score 0):

The second paragraph simply says that *if* $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|X_n - X| \geq \epsilon) \to 0$ then we say $X_n \to X$ in probability. That's just a definition of what "convergence in probability means".

The first paragraph talks about *specific* sequences $X_i$ - namely of those which are independent and identically distributed. You may view those as samples drawn (with replacement) from a fixed population with *cumulative distribution function* (CDF) $D$.

You are correct that such a sequence of samples in general *won't* converge in probability. In fact, they never do unless the distribution of the $X_i$ is degenerate, i.e. there's an $x$ with $P(X_i = x) = 1$.

They *do*, however converge in *distribution*, which is a weaker form of convergence, and means that the *cumulative distribution function* (CDF) of $X_n$ converges pointwise to $D$, i.e. that $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n \leq x) = D(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. They trivially do so - since all the $X_i$ have the *same* CDF, you don't even need a limit - you already have that $P(X_n \leq x) = D(x)$.